# Output of fgets does not match formatting of file

Tags: php, shell, filestream, fopen, fgets

I try to save the output of the linux command `ifconfig` into a variable and show it in my html. I have two pages, one `test.html` and one `ajax.php`. If i click on a link on `test.html` then then an ajax request is made to `ajax.php`which executes ifconfig and sends the result back to `test.html` where the whole html of the body tag is replaced with the output.

I have this code in my `ajax.php`. As you can see, i write the output of `ifconfig` into a file, so i can read each line from the filestream and output them.

```
shell_exec ("/sbin/ifconfig > /tmp/ifconfig 2>&1");
$ifconfig = fopen("/tmp/ifconfig","r") or die ("Unable to open file '/tmp/ifconfig'"); 

while(!feof($ifconfig))
{     
    echo fgets($ifconfig). "<br>";     
}

fclose($ifconfig);
```

But instead of an output like this:

```
 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0A:58:C2:71:7A:90  
           inet addr:172.15.47.121  Bcast:172.25.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:238319 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:122439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:21355179 (20.3 MiB)  TX bytes:19679738 (18.7 MiB)
```

I get this output:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 0A:58:C2:71:7A:905
inet addr:172.15.47.121 Bcast:172.15.255.223 Mask:255.255.0.0
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:23405 errors:0 dropped:14 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:16390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:1613474 (1.5 MiB) TX bytes:19949404 (19.0 MiB)
```

Can someone tell me how i can get the output in the same formatting as it actually is?
**Note**: the addresses are not real, i changed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your output should be for the website, just wrap it into [`<pre></pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tags:

```
echo "<pre>";
while(!feof($ifconfig))
{
    echo fgets($ifconfig). "<br>";
}
echo "</pre>";
```

In `pre` tags the most browsers use `monospace` as font, so it looks a bit more like direct console output.

Answer (score 1):

The output is mangled because spaces are handled very differently in an html page (they are not rendered although they're here, have a look at your page source code).

You might be interested in the CSS property `white-space` applied to a parent html tag to change this behavior :

```
<body style="white-space:pre-wrap">
Your php here
</body>
```